# Can not call many function : Zend_View_Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can not call many function: `Zend_View_Helper`

**helpers : MainHelpers.php**

```
Class Zend_View_Helper_MainHelpers {
  public function mainHelpers(){
    $output="ok 1";
    return $output;
}

  public function mainHelpers2(){
    $output="ok 2";
    return $output;
  } 
}
```

**view : detail.phtml**

```
 <?php echo $this->mainHelpers(); ?>  // ok call function
 <?php echo $this->mainHelpers2(); ?> // not ok call function
```

I want to call many function in `zend_view_helper`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your view helper to contain additional methods besides its constructor, make sure you return the object instance and do something like this:

```
Class Zend_View_Helper_MainHelpers {
  public function mainhelpers() {
      return $this;
  }
  public function foo(){
    $output="ok 1";
    return $output;
  }

  public function bar(){
   $output="ok 2";
   return $output;
  } 
}
```

Now call your helper methods like this:

```
$this->mainhelpers()->foo()
$this->mainhelpers()->bar()
```

Judging from your code example, it seems you are trying to encapsulate more than one view helper inside one class. You are probably better of by creating more view helpers:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Foo()
{
     public function foo() 
     {
         // do stuff
     }
}

class Zend_View_Helper_Bar()
{
     public function bar() 
     {
         // do more stuff
     }
}
```